# What are these .s and .x files alongside my executable?

Tags: .net, windows, esri, arcobjects

We have some applications built against .NET 3.5 and referencing ESRI ArcObjects .NET DLLs (which in turn reference COM DLLs). We're running them on Windows 2008.

Sometimes I will look in the applications' installation directories and alongside the EXEs there are a list of files with `.s` and `.x` extensions.

[image: Listing of .x and .s files]

I wondered if they were generated if the program crashes, but if it is then it doesn't appear to be consistent. The file names are all in the pattern "xx#####", where ##### are numbers, which I thought may have been related to process IDs but I'm not certain about that.

I didn't put those files there, and I can't find any information as to what they are. What are they and why are they there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears these are ESRI-related files.  They are not anything to do with .NET per se.

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=284781

Comment: Thanks very much. The [ArcGIS docs reference](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?topicname=temporary_files_created_by_geoprocessing_tools) in the forum link explains why they're created alongside the EXE: "When tools are run inside a script, the scratch files will be written to the folder where the script is stored."